# Windows 10 - Low power pop up not showing anymore

Tags: windows, windows-10

I used to get a popup warning about the less than 10% battery power, but, I don't know why, it doesn't show up anymore.

Any idea how I can get it back? It's pretty annoying since I don't realize the computer is running out of battery and it suddenly suspends.

The notifications are active (??)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open Power Options by right clicking battery icon, or going to control panel, or executing `powerdfg.cpl`. In front of your active power profile, click `Change plan settings` and then `Change advanced power settings`. Expand `Battery` and then expand `Low battery notifiation`. Turn it on for plugged/unplugged situations.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I was already active but it didn't appear though...